# Calling Rest API in a loop

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Let's assume I get game orders by calling a local web site's API. (A local web site selling game codes, when a user makes a purchase on the web site, I am getting orders from this web site's API.) I will do this with a .net core console app which will check the web site's API every 10 minutes. Now assume I get 5 game orders from the web site's API. Inside of this .net core console app, I will call my API in order to complete the purchase of these 5 game orders as follows. (I am calling 3rd party Rest APIs in order to get game codes.)

Can you please check my code and give me some feedback\suggestions? Is there any place to cause a problem?

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
          // Assume I am getting game orders from the web site here
          //
            .....

            const int numberOfProducts = webSiteGameOrders;
            try
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < numberOfProducts; i++)
                {
                    var product = webSiteProduct;
                   
                    //DEV
                    var request =
                        (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://test//api/purchase");

                    var svcCredentials =
                        Convert.ToBase64String(
                            Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username" + ":" + "password"));

                    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + svcCredentials);
                    request.Method = "POST";
                    request.KeepAlive = false;
                    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                    {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("productCode", webSiteProduct),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("quantity", "1"),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("shopNo", "1"),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("safeNo", "1"),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("cashierNo", "1")

                    });


                    var formUrlEncodedContent = content;
                    var urlEncodedString = await formUrlEncodedContent.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(await request.GetRequestStreamAsync()))
                    {
                        streamWriter.Write(urlEncodedString);
                    }

                    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)(await request.GetResponseAsync());

                    var response = new HttpResponseMessage
                    {
                        StatusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode,
                        Content = new StreamContent(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()),
                    };

                    //Read response
                    var htmlResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var deserializedResult = JObject.Parse(htmlResponse);
                    
                    Console.WriteLine((string)deserializedResult["coupons"]?[0]?["Serial"] + ":" + (string)deserializedResult["coupons"]?[0]?["Pin"]);
                }

              

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE:**
Here is how I end up:

```
    public class BusinessService : IHostedService
    {
        private IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
        private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _applicationLifetime;
        private IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        public BusinessService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime, IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<BusinessService> logger)
        {
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
            _applicationLifetime = applicationLifetime;
            _configuration = configuration;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogCritical("Critical!");
            _logger.LogInformation("Application starts: ");
            await MakeRequestsToRemoteService();
            //Stop Application
            _applicationLifetime.StopApplication();
            _logger.LogInformation("Application stops: ");
        }

        public async Task MakeRequestsToRemoteService()
        {
            try
            {
                HttpClient httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("OrdersClient");

                var authenticationBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("zWedH5OUUp");

                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                    Convert.ToBase64String(authenticationBytes));
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://api.test.com/orders?startDate=1612126800000");


                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Root orders = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Root>();


                    foreach (var content in orders.Content)
                    {
                        Console.Write(content.CustomerId + " " + content.CustomerFirstName + " " +
                                      content.CustomerLastName + " " + content.CustomerEmail + " " + content.TotalPrice +
                                      " " + content.InvoiceAddress.Phone + " " + content.Lines[0].ProductCode + " " +
                                      content.Lines[0].ProductName);

                        _logger.LogInformation("Order {ID} {CustomerId}, {Name} {LastName}, {Phone}, {ProductCode}, {ProductName}, {Price}, {OrderDate} ", content.Id, content.CustomerId, content.CustomerFirstName, content.CustomerLastName, content.InvoiceAddress.Phone, content.Lines[0].ProductCode, content.Lines[0].ProductName, content.TotalPrice, DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(content.OrderDate).DateTime);

                        InsertData(content);
                    }


                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Error: {Error} ", e.Message);
                throw;
            }
            
            
            
        }

        public void InsertData(Content content)
        {
           
            var connString = _configuration["ConnectionStrings:Development"];
            using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = sqlConnection;
                    string sql = @"insert into Orders (id, customerId, firstName, lastName, phone, productCode, productName, price, orderDate, status) values (@id, @customerId, @firstName, @lastName, @phone, @productCode, @productName, @price, @orderDate, @status)";
                    command.CommandText = sql;
                    
                    try
                    {
                        command.Parameters.Add("id", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = content.Id;
                        command.Parameters.Add("customerId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = content.CustomerId;
                        command.Parameters.Add("firstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = content.CustomerFirstName;
                        command.Parameters.Add("lastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = content.CustomerLastName;
                        command.Parameters.Add("phone", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = content.InvoiceAddress.Phone;
                        command.Parameters.Add("productCode", SqlDbType.Int).Value = content.Lines[0].ProductCode;
                        command.Parameters.Add("productName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = content.Lines[0].ProductName;
                        command.Parameters.Add("price", SqlDbType.Float).Value = content.TotalPrice;
                        command.Parameters.Add("orderDate", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = content.OrderDate;
                        command.Parameters.Add("status", SqlDbType.TinyInt).Value = 1; //Retrieved

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (SqlException exception)
                    {
                        if (exception.Number == 2627) // Cannot insert duplicate key row in object error
                        {
                            _logger.LogInformation("Duplicate: {ID} ", content.Id);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _logger.LogError("Error: {Error} ", exception.Message);
                            throw; // Throw exception if this exception is unexpected
                        }
                           
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any problem you are facing in this code?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, I didn't test very well just made a couple of tests. There is no error so far but I wonder if you have suggestions\advices?

Comment: Can you check how many connections are getting opened and closed between 10 minutes interval. If more than 10 connections or any connections are opened between these intervals or after executing one set of request then you might get slow response after some time or it may return some error as connection resource are getting exhausted.

Comment: Advice: use `HttpClient` instead of `WebRequest`. Use `streamWriter.WriteAsync` method.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, what is the benefit of HttpClient over WebRequest? If I use either of them with async it should be good for the performance point of view as it will not block the resources waiting for the response and you will get good throughput.

Comment: The `WebRequest` class is deprecated and no longer recommended for development. At the same time, `HttpClient` supports all modern standards and has better performance.

Comment: I will recommend 
1. to create httpclient only once.
2 . use Task.WaitAll (tasks) , so your for loop not wait for next process. or avoid cpu process to wait.